# CSS Button hover change color won't work

Tags: html, css

```
div ul li a.button:hover {
  text-color:#FF0000;
  background: #0040FF;
}
```

I am trying to get a button that is Blue with white text change to a lighter blue with red text when it is hovered over however it doesn't seem to work. This is the button code and here is where it is supposed to be applied:

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li><a href= "index.html"><span>Home</span></a></li>
    <li><a href= "about.html"><span>About</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="help.html"><span>Help</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="links.html"><span>Links</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="About Me.html"><span>About Me</span></a></li>
  <ul>
</div>
```

each button is the same and I want the hover to work the same, however it will not work when uploaded to my website.

Comment: The CSS property is `color` not `text-color`... also, there are no elements with a class of `.button` in the HTML you posted.. here is an updated example with corrections - http://jsfiddle.net/sc78rqLv/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `background-color: #0040FF;`

and add the `.button` class to your links like `<a class="button"....>....</a>`

Answer (score 0):

Change your css to:

```
div ul li a.button:hover {
    color:#FF0000;
    background-color: #0040FF;
}
```

Try changing the text-color to color and add the class as well.

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li><a class="button" href= "index.html"><span>Home</span></a></li>
    <li><a class="button" href= "about.html"><span>About</span></a></li>
    <li><a class="button" href="help.html"><span>Help</span></a></li>
    <li><a class="button" href="links.html"><span>Links</span></a></li>
    <li><a class="button" href="About Me.html"><span>About Me</span></a></li>
    <ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no such property as `text-color`

This should work:

```
div ul li a.button:hover {
  color:#FF0000;
  background: #0040FF;
}
```

And you forgot to add the class to those a -elements

Answer (score 0):

remove the button from css

```
div ul li a:hover {
  color:#FF0000;
  background: #0040FF;
}
```